# How to select all the SQL rows from a table (With a unique combination of two columns) where the same combination is not already in another table

Tags: c#, mysql, database, select

I'm having a little difficulty phrasing exactly what my problem is, but I'll do my best. I'm working with C# in Visual Studio, connecting to a SQL database.

I have a used book store database where sellers can come in and give their book to us to sell for them. There are three key tables:

- Book (Contains the 10 books that we sell, each with a unique ISBN identifying the book)
- Sold (All books that have been sold, identified by the book's ISBN and the ID [Called SSBID] of the original seller)
- Copy (All books that have ever existed in the DB, including the ones that have been sold. Identified by the same ISBN and seller ID [Called SSID])

We can assume that an original seller will never sell the same book twice.

When a customer comes to buy a book, the clerk will look up each book via two drop down lists. The first DDL is populated with each ISBN that has a book in the system, demonstrated below. (No need to list an ISBN if it doesn't exist!)

```
SELECT DISTINCT [ISBN] FROM [Copy] ORDER BY [ISBN]
```

The second drop down list is supposed to populate with the seller ID of each seller who is selling a book with that same ISBN. However, we do not want to list the seller ID of any books that already have been sold. The select statement that makes the most sense to me is below, but I do not believe that the logic is perfect.

```
SELECT [SSID] FROM [Copy] WHERE (SSID, ISBN NOT IN (SELECT SSBID, ISBN FROM Sold)) AND ([ISBN] = @ISBN) ORDER BY [SSID]
```

So, we do not want to pull any records that have the same unique combination of SSID and ISBN in both Copy and Sold, while at the same time only showing the records that correspond to the ISBN we have already selected.

What should the second query look like?
Is the fact that SSID and SSBID have different names going to affect the function of the query?

For clarity, here is a rough layout of Copy and Sold:

Copy

```
- SSID_______ISBN
 - 115________019
 - 115________528
 - 123________528
 - 503________019
```

Sold

```
- SSBID_____ISBN
 - 115_______019
```

So after selecting "115" in my first drop down, the second drop down should populate with only "528".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to join both `Sold` and `Copy` on `ISBN` unless there's a record in both `Sold` *and* `Copy` that matches on both `ISBN` *and* `SSID`.
I might be way, way off, but perhaps this will help.

```
SELECT b.ISBN, b.SSID
FROM
    Books b
    JOIN Sold s on b.ISBN = s.ISBN 
    JOIN Copy c on b.ISBN = c.ISBN
    LEFT JOIN Sold s2 on b.ISBN = s2.ISBN and b.SSID = s2.SSID
    LEFT JOIN Copy c2 on b.ISBN = c2.ISBN and b.SSID = c2.SSID
WHERE s2.ISBN is null or c2.ISBN is null
```

That's going to JOIN to both `Sold` and `Copy` on `ISBN`, but exclude records where `Books` matches both tables on both fields.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I think I may have added a little more information than was necessary. The Book table shouldn't really figure into the problem here.  Basically, I want to pull all of the records of the Copy table that are not in the Sold table, but I need to do this with a matching unique set of two ID's (SSID and ISBN). You are right, a LEFT JOIN with the IS NULL is the right way to do that, but how do I do it while matching 2 columns? Like this?     SELECT SSID FROM Copy A LEFT JOIN Sold B ON (A.SSID = B.SSBID AND A.ISBN = B.ISBN) 
WHERE (B.SSBID AND B.ISBN) IS NULL

Comment: Finally got it working. I used " SELECT A.SSID FROM Copy A LEFT JOIN Sold B ON A.SSID = B.SSBID AND A.ISBN = B.ISBN
WHERE (B.SSBID IS NULL OR B.ISBN IS NULL)  AND (A.[ISBN] = @ISBN) "  I kept getting the "Ambiguous Column Name" error, until I added the "A.[ISBN]". It's working great now!